# Does every Mongoldb GridFS chunk represent each physical file in disk

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

In normal Mongodb collection, each chunk actually just is each physical file in disk, right? But in GridFS, mongoDB still treat each chunk as each physical file in disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

A mongo server will read data from files found on a specific path. 
A mongod config server, from a sharded cluster, will read data from  different place than the data server, he has his own data files which store chunks metadata.

Depending on the storage engine used, data will be written in files up to 2GB on MMAPv1 engine or larger files in Wired Tiger engine.